# Replace element that has changed in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I have an array of attendees, 2 of them are also instructors. I want to update one of the instructors by replacing him/her and leave the remaining attendees intact in the array.

Here's an example:

```
    {   
      attendees: [ 
        { email: 'instructor1@gmail.com' },
        { email: 'instructor2@gmail.com' },
        { email: 'attendee@gmail.com' },
        { email: 'attendee1@gmail.com' },
        { email: 'attendee2@gmail.com' } 
      ]
    }
```

Now I submit a new array of instructors with one of them changed:

```
    {
      instructors: [
        { email : 'test@gmail.com' },
        { email : 'instructor2@gmail.com' }
      ]
    }
```

And my final result should be:

```
    {   
      attendees: [ 
        { email: 'test@gmail.com' },
        { email: 'instructor2@gmail.com' },
        { email: 'attendee@gmail.com' },
        { email: 'attendee1@gmail.com' },
        { email: 'attendee2@gmail.com' } 
      ]
    }
```

Where `test@gmail.com` has replaced `instructor1@gmail.com` as the new instructor. I think I can use _.differenceBy with lodash but can't figure out how to replace the changed element in the array. Is there an elegant way to do this?

Comment: `Array#concat(Array)`

Comment: This doesn't seem to make sense. In the original set the only way to know something is an instructor is by inspecting the email. After the replacement, there's no way to know that 'test' is an instructor. Is that what you want?

Comment: Your attendee and instructor arrays would need an extra attribute for each person, like `id`, where they can be identified with and matched across the 2 arrays.

Comment: Do the atteendees and instructors share the same index? Eg. attendees[0] === instructors[0]? In that case something like this https://jsfiddle.net/wyL19ojr/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a few solutions that either 1) puts the updates in a new variable or 2) updates the attendees variable. Of course, this is pretty limited because your data doesn't have something akin to a primary key (ie: an ID field). If you do have a primary key, then you can modify these examples to check the id.

```
var attendees = [ 
    { email: 'instructor1@gmail.com' },
    { email: 'instructor2@gmail.com' },
    { email: 'attendee@gmail.com' },
    { email: 'attendee1@gmail.com' },
    { email: 'attendee2@gmail.com' } 
]

var instructors = [
    { email : 'test@gmail.com' },
    { email : 'instructor2@gmail.com' }
]

// 1) in a new variable
var updatedAttendees = attendees.map(function(item, index) {
    return instructors[index] || item;
})

// 2) In the same variable
for (var i = 0; i < attendees.length; i++) {
    if (instructors[i]) {
        attendees[i] = instructors[i];
    }
}
```

If you did have a primary key, it might look like this.  Note that we now have two nested loops.  This example is not optimized at all, but just to give you the general idea:

```
var attendeesWithId = [
    { id: 1, email: 'instructor1@gmail.com' },
    { id: 2, email: 'instructor2@gmail.com' },
    { id: 3, email: 'attendee@gmail.com' },
    { id: 4, email: 'attendee1@gmail.com' },
    { id: 5, email: 'attendee2@gmail.com' } 
]

var updates = [
    { id: 4, email: 'something-different@gmail.com' },
]

for (var j = 0; j < updates.length; j++) {
    var update = updates[j];

    for (var i = 0; i < attendeesWithId.length; i++) {
        if (update.id === attendeesWithId[i].id) {
            attendeesWithId[i] = update;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this help

```js
var initialData =  {   
      attendees: [ 
        { email: 'instructor1@gmail.com' },
        { email: 'instructor2@gmail.com' },
        { email: 'attendee@gmail.com' },
        { email: 'attendee1@gmail.com' },
        { email: 'attendee2@gmail.com' } 
      ]
    }

var updateWithThis = {
      instructors: [
        { email : 'test@gmail.com' },
        { email : 'instructor2@gmail.com' }
      ]
    }

for(var i=0; i< updateWithThis.instructors.length;i++){
    initialData.attendees[i] = updateWithThis.instructors[i];
}

document.write(JSON.stringify(initialData));
```